# Getting Error "Request Error: No ad to show" in AdMob Native ads iOS

Tags: ios, admob, native-ads

I have developed native adMob in my application by coping code from Sample Application given by google from below URL https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/master/Objective-C/admob/NativeExample

I am getting: Error by using my AdUnitID:  failed with error: Request Error: No ad to show.

But when i use test key given in Google sample app than my application native ads are working fine.

So What is the problem with my native Ad unitId ?

Google Native AdUnitID : ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3986624511 My App Native AdUnitID : ca-app-pub-3415315092173981/2210049154

Update: When i put "testDevices" with my application UnitID than my application native ads are working fine. but when i remove "testDevices" than getting same error.

Answer (score 2):

Try with the ad unit ID for testing: `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2562852117`

Also, if the height is too small, then there will be no ads too. For a "small" ad, I have to set to 140 height for it to show up.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if there are no ads it will give error that no ads are available.

Comment: Well... duh! The question is why we get this "No ad to show" error, even though there are definitely ads to show.